# Faild composer network deploy with time out

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I executed this command.

```
composer network deploy -a basic-sample-network.bna -p defaultProfile -i admin -s Xurw3yU9zI0l
```

But,faild with time out..

Here is log.

```
Deploying business network from archive: basic-sample-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: basic-sample-network@0.0.10
    Description: The Hello World of Hyperledger Composer samples

✖ Deploying business network definition. This may take a minute...

timed out waiting for transaction to complete
Command failed
```

Colud you tell me the way to composer network deploy with no time out.

Answer (score 0):

this is a Fabric issue I've seen reported elsewhere.

It seems `docker logs 47525938ac95` posted earlier reveals the issue.

From your command line you will need to pull the base image (you may already have done) - and docker tag it:

eg.
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.1.0  (or whatever baseimage version you prefer).

docker tag hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.1.0 hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:latest

then retry

Basically, when you deploy the chaincode, the peer node requests to docker to run the fabric-baseimage to run the chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I use Hyperledger Fabric v0.6 environment.

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~/composer/bna$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
3f3f0b3b6156        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:7150->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7151->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7152->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7153->7053/tcp   fabricconfig_vp1_1
f9819ca1fc89        hyperledger/composer-playground                      "pm2-docker compos..."   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                                                                           fabricconfig_composer_1
6488421e4878        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:7350->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7351->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7352->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7353->7053/tcp   fabricconfig_vp3_1
886c5594bba2        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:7250->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7251->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7252->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7253->7053/tcp   fabricconfig_vp2_1
1c407073c7ec        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050-7053->7050-7053/tcp                                                                 fabricconfig_vp0_1
ae2cd708ecc1        hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc:x86_64-0.6.1-preview   "membersrvc"             5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                                                                           fabricconfig_membersrvc_1
```

thanks

Comment: can you post the peer logs which may contain information as to what the problem is. The command is of the format 'docker logs <CONTAINER ID>' and the container id is the value as shown from the docker ps command.

Answer (score 0):

This is new CONTEINER ID.

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~/composer/bna$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
180a05ba4a66        hyperledger/composer-playground                      "pm2-docker compos..."   6 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                                                                           fabricconfig_composer_1
47525938ac95        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   6 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7150->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7151->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7152->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7153->7053/tcp   fabricconfig_vp1_1
962df523b480        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   6 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7350->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7351->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7352->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7353->7053/tcp   fabricconfig_vp3_1
6ea2ec92d454        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   6 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7250->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7251->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7252->7052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7253->7053/tcp   fabricconfig_vp2_1
fb09850fba53        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.6.1-preview         "sh -c 'sleep 5; p..."   6 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050-7053->7050-7053/tcp                                                                 fabricconfig_vp0_1
1e5d14cacb02        hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc:x86_64-0.6.1-preview   "membersrvc"             6 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                                                                           fabricconfig_membersrvc_1
```

Here is 'docker logs '
It looks like connection error.

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~/composer/bna$ docker logs 47525938ac95
:
04:59:24.290 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 117 Error building images: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:latest not found
04:59:24.290 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 118 Image Output:
********************
Step 1/4 : FROM hyperledger/fabric-baseimage

********************
```

and

```
  vagrant@ubuntu:~/composer/bna$ docker logs 962df523b480
    :
    02:51:31.563 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 15aa Error creating connection to peer address 172.18.0.5:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
    :
```

and

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~/composer/bna$ docker logs 6ea2ec92d454
:
02:54:25.298 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 1a05 Error creating connection to peer address 172.18.0.5:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
:
```

and

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~/composerPoCTool-master/tools/composer/bna$ docker logs fb09850fba53
:
02:55:48.718 [peer] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 1c33 Error creating connection to peer address 172.18.0.5:7051: grpc: timed out when dialing
:
```